# Azure Bicep: setting a null value if the property doesn't exist

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I am deploying schedules for the azure update management service through bicep. My code is as below:

```
param parSchedules array = [
  {
    name: 'mysched1'
    monthlyOccurrencesDay: null
    monthlyOccurrencesOccurence: null
    DaysOfWeek: 'Wednesday'
    StartTime: '${parBaseTimeForUpdateSchedules}T19:00:00'
    tag: {
      Update: [
        'tag1'
      ]
    }
  }
  {
    name: 'mysched2'
    monthlyOccurrencesDay: 'Wednesday'
    monthlyOccurrencesOccurence: 1
    DaysOfWeek: 'Wednesday'
    StartTime: '${parBaseTimeForUpdateSchedules}T07:00:00'
    tag: {
      Update: [
        'tag2'
      ]
    }
  }
]


resource resUpdateschedule 'Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/softwareUpdateConfigurations@2019-06-01' = [for schedule in parSchedules: {
  name: schedule.name
  parent: resAutomationAccount
  properties: {
    scheduleInfo: {
      advancedSchedule: {
        monthlyOccurrences: [
          {
            day: schedule.monthlyOccurrencesDay
            occurrence: schedule.monthlyOccurrencesOccurence
          }
        ]
        weekDays: [
          schedule.DaysOfWeek
        ]
      }
      description: ''
      frequency: 'Week'
      interval: 1
      isEnabled: true
      startTime: schedule.StartTime
      timeZone: 'UTC'
    }
    updateConfiguration: {
      duration: 'PT2H'
      operatingSystem: 'Windows'
      targets: {
        azureQueries: [
          {
            locations: [
              parLocation
            ]
            scope: [
              subscription().id
            ]
            tagSettings: {
              tags: schedule.tag
            }
          }
        ]
      }
      windows: {
        includedUpdateClassifications: 'Critical, Security'
        rebootSetting: 'IfRequired'
      }
    }
  }
}]
```

I am getting error with this because null value is not accepted for **monthlyOccurrencesDay** and monthlyOccurrencesOccurence. So what I want is to be able to use the same list containing different types of schedules (with and without **monthlyOccurrencesOccurence**) by looping the same resource. Like **if the values of monthlyOccurrencesOccurence is null, it shouldn't take into consideration this property.** Is that possible at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to conditionally set the monthly occurence like that:

```bicep
resource resUpdateschedule 'Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/softwareUpdateConfigurations@2019-06-01' = [for schedule in parSchedules: {
  name: schedule.name
  ...
  properties: {
    scheduleInfo: {
      advancedSchedule: {
        monthlyOccurrences: schedule.monthlyOccurrencesOccurence != null ? [
          {
            day: schedule.monthlyOccurrencesDay
            occurrence: schedule.monthlyOccurrencesOccurence
          }
        ] : []
        ...
      }
      ...
    }
    ...
  }
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `contains` function.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/bicep-functions-object#contains

contains(monthlyOccurrences, 'monthlyOccurrences'). This will return true if the  monthlyOccurrences contains a property named monthlyOccurrences.